# scrollable canvas with unknown amount of radio boxes tkinter

Tags: python, tkinter, scrollbar

I am trying to set a canvas with a scrollbar, the canvas contains an unknown amount of radio boxes, so far i have this code, which i can set to unknown size, but i have 2 problems:
1) the scrollbar is there, you can move it but it wont work
2) i don't know how to set it to unknown size of radio boxes

here is my code:

```
# creating 2 frames and tkinter master window
master = Tk()
master.title("Navigator Tool")
master.geometry("700x400")
frame1 = Frame(master, width=700, height=150)
frame2 = Frame(master, width=700, height=250)
frame1.pack(fill=BOTH)
frame2.pack(fill=BOTH)
#set scroll for favorites
canvas = Canvas(frame2, width=700, height=250,scrollregion=(0,0,500,500))
scroll_win = Scrollbar(frame2, orient=VERTICAL)
scroll_win.config(command=canvas.yview)
scroll_win.pack(side=RIGHT, fill=Y)
canvas.config(yscrollcommand=scroll_win.set)
canvas.pack(side=LEFT, fill=BOTH, expand=True)

favorites = []
for x in range(20):
    favorites.append(("file"+str(x), "file"+str(x)))

for text, value in favorites:
    r = Radiobutton(canvas, text=text, value=value)
    r.pack()
```

The amount on this example is 20, but usually it wont be known
Thank you

Comment: The TKinter reference guide at http://infohost.nmt.edu/tcc/help/pubs/tkinter/web/index.html has a tutorial on connecting a scrollbar to another widget. Follow that example, and pack your radiobuttons into the Canvas object (or use a Frame inside the Frame).

Comment: On further thought, using a scrolled listbox (the example in the above tutorial) is a better way to go - you can force it to only accept one input (like a set of radiobuttons).